# Mouse Does Not Move in Ubuntu Live

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, mouse, bios

The installed OS is Windows 7 64 Bit. I am attempting to try out Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 by selecting the boot without install option (Ubuntu live) from a USB drive. Once Ubuntu boots the mouse curser appears in the desktop but it does not move.

The mouse works in Windows 7, and while in BIOS settings. But during the Ubuntu boot the mouse's laser turns off and does not illuminate again.

I have a 4TB disk for which I will need full use of. So legacy drivers are not an option. I must use UEFI.

The current state of the relevant BIOS settings in the Peripherals tab are:

> IIOMMV Controller: Enabled
>
> OS Type: Other OS
>
> Boot Mode Selection: UEFI and Legacy
>
> LAN PXE Boot Option ROM: Disabled
>
> Storage Boot Option Control: UEFI First

During the Ubuntu boot the screen is filled with IO Page Fault errors.

The keyboard works I think because it is using a PS2 port. The mouse is USB.

The board model is Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P. The graphics card is an Nvidia GTX 760

What do I need to do to get the mouse working?

I am concerned that if I go ahead with an Ubuntu installation on the hard drive the mouse will also not work there.

Comment: Your concerns are warranted. Yours is one of the motherboards with a broken IOMMU. You need to disable that in UEFI and add "iommu=soft" to the Grub  entry, both when running a live session, when installing and after install (it can be made permanent after install). Otherwise you won't have USBs and other devices. Also you need to boot and install Ubuntu in the same way (Legacy or UEFI) the already installed OS was, or you won't be able to dual boot.

Comment: Boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) and size of hard disk are unrelated; you can use large disks with a BIOS/CSM/legacy boot; *however,* Windows (but not Linux) ties boot mode to partition table type (BIOS to MBR; EFI to GPT). To effectively use an over-2TiB disk, GPT is required. Thus, in a dual-boot configuration, *Windows* must boot in EFI mode. Ubuntu could, in principle, boot in BIOS mode, but mixing boot modes is tricky. If you can confirm that a BIOS-mode boot doesn't exhibit your mouse problem, this might be worth pursuing, but I'm skeptical that this would be the case.

Comment: I do not intend to dual boot. The intention is to completely remove Windows 7 and replace it with Ubuntu-Mate. This is due to WIndows privacy issues:https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/malware-microsoft.en.html http://www.extremetech.com/computing/213183-once-more-with-tracking-microsoft-backports-privacy-invading-windows-10-features-to-windows-7-8

Comment: Is the broken IOMMU a hardware design issue, or a BIOS firmware issue?

Comment: When I have IOMMU disabled what I get when I boot Ubuntu-Mate live is only the shell. The desktop does not appear. After adding the Grub entries how would the Ubuntu-Mate desktop be invoked?

Comment: You also need *nomodeset* in grub along with the other. It should boot the live session in low graphics mode but it's enough to install. Then add again both parameters when booting the first time and install the recommended Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @CelticWarrior : Please provide detailed instructions on how to do this, or a link to them. I found instructions on how to add "iommu=soft" [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=4). But this failed because neither sudo nor gedit are valid commands on Ubuntu-Mate live boot. Also in the live files there is not a file "grub" in the directory /etc/default. I want to get this working in live before I install just make sure I have the procedure right.

Comment: When booting live you simply press "e" to edit the grub entry and add the parameters after quiet splash. Only after installing you make that change in the grub file and run *sudo update-grub* to make it permanent (the iommu parameter, not nomodeset). Gedit is also included in MATE, I think, but you can use any other editor of your choice; *nano* works in the terminal window.

Comment: I have the mouse working in Ubuntu-Mate Live now. The mouse was plugged into a USB 3 port. When I plugged it into a USB 2 port it worked. So I no longer need to edit the grub before installation. I will do this edit after the Ubuntu-Mate installation to get the USB 3 ports working. gedit does not seem to be available in the live shell. I expect it will be available in the installed shell after Ubuntu-Mate installation. Thanks to everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have USB 3 working now. Disabling hardware IOMMU in the UEFI and enabling software IOMMU in grub is what made it work. To do this I followed these directions:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=4

Before I buy anymore boards from Gigabyte, or any other manufacturer, I am going to find out which of them have fully functional IOMMU, most especially in regard to USB 3.0, and consider only those for purchase.

Thank you everyone for your help :)